# Adjust line spacing rather that paragraph spacing at page break

Tags: page-breaking

A `\pagebreak` command causes LaTeX to fill the current page by inserting extra space between the paragraphs. Is there a way to get LaTeX to adjust the space between each line instead of just between paragraphs?

(I'm using LaTeX with the `memoir` class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pagebreak` does not directly affect the inter-paragraph space. It just forces the page to stop short. After that (if `\flushbottom` is in effect) any stretchable space on the page will stretch.

Typically inter-line spacing is set to a fixed length, but you can do

```
\setlength\baselineskip{12pt plus 2pt}
```

which will allow it to stretch between 12 and 14pt, if you really want that.

Comment: Thank you for that, David. I tried it and decided that it was less pretty than just using the default settings. (But I had to try. :-) )